# Looping through Form fields and show all the form fields except hidden field in that form

Tags: jquery

Can any one provide me an example to loop through all the form fields and to show those fields except hidden fields in that form.

Pseudo code:

```
for(i=0;i<formFields.length;i++)
{
if(formFields[i]!= 'hidden field')
then formFields[i].show();
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand. You want to loop through and show all form fields except those that are hidden. Fields without a hidden attribute will be shown. Perhaps show us your data (form fields) and how they are being rendered on the page (i.e. static HTML, JS/jQuery, AngularJS, etc.).

Comment: suppose I have a form say Form1. This form contain following fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looping through the fields with the following code; however, if the fields have a hidden attribute they will be hidden. No need to apply `.show` to elements that will already be displayed.

**Loop through all visibile fields:**

```
$("#Form1 :input").not(':button, :hidden').each(function() {
    // do whatever with the fields here
});
```

**Update**

```
// show form, clear hidden values
$(".dropdown").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Show all fields") {
        $("#Form1").show();
        $("#Form1 :input").is(':hidden').each(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    }
});
```

**Update 2:**

```
$(".dropdown").on('change', function() { 
    if ($(this).val() == "Show all fields") {
        $("#Form1").show();
        $('#Form1 *').filter(':input').each(function() {(...)});
    }
});
```

Comment: suppose I have a form say Form1. This form contain following fields.

 
 <form id="Form1">
  <input type = "text" id="ff1"></input>
  <input type = "text" id="ff2"></input>
  <input type = "text" id="ff3"></input>
  <input type = "hidden" id="h1"></input>
  <input type = "hidden" id="h2"></input>
 </form>

Initially this form will be hidden. In my case whenever a drop down value changes to "Show all fields" all the above form fields (ff1,ff2,ff3) except hidden
fields should be shown. And if it is a hidden field then I need to change its value to empty.

Comment: my form contains text box and dropdown as well. so could you pls modify the code accordingly

Comment: @user3742125 `:input` will select text boxes, dropdown menus, hidden elements, buttons, etc. I'm not sure how I could modify my answer anymore to better fit your needs. If what I have is not working you could try using `.filter`. I've updated my answer to include this. If that doesn't work then I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: thanks I got it... I thought ":input" will select only text boxes..Will check this and let u know

Comment: No problem. Actually, check out this link to the [API](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). It shows what types of form elements will be selected using `:input`.